# Update Multiple columns with no effect

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an API's, in my project we are using dynamic databases so for that one i am connecting databases by using **mysqli** it's working fine i can able to do CRUD operations also on Database but if i try to update multiple columns at that time changes are not reflected in Database did i miss anything can anyone please help me ?

```
$childConnection=  new mysqli(env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'), env('DB_USERNAME', 'test'), env('DB_PASSWORD', ''), $item->dbname,env('DB_PORT', '3306'),env('DB_SOCKET', ''));
$uname="test";
$uid="10";
$childConnection->query("UPDATE users SET name={$uname} WHERE id={$uid}"); // this query is working fine.

 $t_now = Carbon::now();
 $t_sessionStarted = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($userData['log_time']);
 $r_time= $t_sessionStarted->diffForHumans($t_now, ['parts' => 3, 'syntax' => CarbonInterface::DIFF_ABSOLUTE]); //output is "2hours 50minutes"
$childConnection->query("UPDATE users SET ltime={$r_time} WHERE id={$uid}"); //This is not working

Desc users :- ltime is VARCHAR(300)
```

Comment: "_// this query is working fine_" Are you certain about that? `{test}` is missing a `$` and quotes

Comment: VARCHAR cannot be > 255, how is it 300 :)

Comment: could you add to your question the output of query `desc users;` ?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with laravel. it's native PHP + using Carbon package.

Comment: @Ron "_VARCHAR cannot be > 255_" How so? Doesn't it take values from 0 to 65535?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name={$uname}` should be `name='{$uname}'` since it is a string

same for `SET ltime={$r_time}` should be `SET ltime='{$r_time}'`

also VARCHAR cannot be > 255

Comment: Thanks it's working fine but why it's working for `name={$uname}` previously